# c# method does not fire when input is created at runtime

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I tried below code and result was successful :

```
<asp:Content runat="server" ID="CNT1" ContentPlaceHolderID="CPH1">
    <div id ="CNT" runat="server">
        <input name="btnName" type="submit" runat="server" id="btnId" clientidmode="Static" value="btnVal" OnServerClick="btnClick"/>
    </div>
</asp:Content>

    protected void btnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string id = ((HtmlInputSubmit)sender).ID;
        //rest of code
    }
```

but when i try add my input at run time  the c# method does not fier. 
I tried below code :

```
CNT.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<input name=\"btnName\" type=\"submit\" runat=\"server\" id=\"btnId\" clientidmode=\"Static\" value=\"btnVal\" OnServerClick=\"btnClick\"/>")
```

Comment: From the documentaiton of LiteralControl (emphasis mine): `Represents HTML elements, text, and any other strings in an ASP.NET page that **do not require processing on the server.**`. You can't use ServerClick with a literal control.

Comment: so what's the solution?

Comment: Add a control that is suitable for server-side processing, such as a [Button](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an `HtmlInputSubmit` Object and set the properties as desired.

Then append `OnServerClick event handler` to the newly created control.

Next add this control to the `Controls` collection